# Showing the equality of two rook polynomials.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I'm reading Barbeau's *Polynomials*.

> [image]

I've done the following: Taking an arbitrary chessboard $C$ with some of the squares forbidden (with $n$ being the number of squares and $F$ the number of free squares), I'd have:

$$C=\binom{n-F}{0}t^0+\binom{n-F}{1}t^1+\binom{n-F}{2}t^2+\dots+\binom{n-F}{c}t^c$$

Then I guess that $C_1$ would be:

$$C_1=\binom{n-F-1}{0}t^0+\binom{n-F-1}{1}t^1+\binom{n-F-1}{2}t^2+\dots+\binom{n-F-1}{c}t^c$$

For $C_2$, I guess that I'd have to speak about other number of free squares, $f$ for example:

$$C_2=\binom{n-f}{0}t^0+\binom{n-f}{1}t^1+\binom{n-f}{2}t^2+\dots+\binom{n-f}{c-1}t^{c-1}$$

Now, to show that $C=C_1+C_2$, I guess that I'd need to sum the terms this way:

$$\binom{n-F-1}{x}t^x+ \binom{n-f}{x}t^x=\frac{(n-F-1)!}{x!(n-F-1-x)!}t^x+\frac{(n-f)!}{x!(n-f-x)!}t^x$$

But from here, I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hardly need any formulas at all, just focus on the $r_k$.

Consider a valid configuration on board $C$.
Either there is a rook on $S$ or there is no rook on $S$.

If there is a rook on $S$, there cannot be any rook in the entire row or column containing $S$, so the remaining $k-1$ rooks are determined by the placement of $k-1$ rooks in $C_2$.

On the other hand the valid configurations without a rook on $S$ correspond to the valid placements of $k$ rooks on $C_1$.

So $r_k(C)=r_k(C_1)+r_{k-1}(C_2)$.

Now multiply with $t^k$ and sum over $k\geq 1$ to get the desired relation between the rook polynomials.

Comment: "If there is a rook on $S$, there cannot be any rook in the entire row or column containing $S$" - Why? I don't get it. Take for example the following chessboard:

$$\begin{matrix}
{\bullet }&{\underline{\bullet}}&{\bullet}&{\bullet}\\ 
{\underline{\bullet}}&{\star }&{\underline{\bullet}}&{\underline{\bullet}}\\ 
{\bullet}&{\underline{\bullet}}&{\bullet}&{\bullet}\\ 
{\bullet}&{\underline{\bullet}}&{\bullet}&{\bullet}
\end{matrix}$$

It has a rook on $(2,2)$, it could also have rooks in all the remaining squares, no?

Comment: Read the exercise: no two are allowed in the same tow or in the same column.

Comment: Oh, yes. I just saw it now. Thanks.